# Installing a higiher version of GCC on Raspian Wheezy that doesn't rely on a newer glibc

Tags: c++, gcc, raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian

We have software that we distributed to a bunch of Pis that have Raspian Wheezy. Recently, we've added in a bit of code that uses C++ standards that aren't integrated until >=gcc-4.8. If I compile on a newer version of Raspian, there are glibc mismatch errors when running on the Wheezy installed Pis.

Can I get >=gcc-4.8 on one of the Wheezy Pis without also having to install a higher version of glibc (which automatically makes any binary compiled refuse to work on the other Pis)?

Side note:
I've been trying to compile gcc-4.8 but I'm having the worst time because it keeps throwing a bits/predefs.h is missing error. Even though I configured it with --disable-multilib:

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-20150611/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc'
# If this is the top-level multilib, build all the other
# multilibs.
/root/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-20150611/host-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/gcc/xgcc -B/root/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-20150611/host-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/gcc/ -B/usr/local/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ -B/usr/local/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include -isystem /usr/local/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/sys-include    -g -O2 -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -fPIC -fno-inline -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector   -fPIC -fno-inline -I. -I. -I../../host-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/gcc -I../.././libgcc -I../.././libgcc/. -I../.././libgcc/../gcc -I../.././libgcc/../include  -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -o _muldi3.o -MT _muldi3.o -MD -MP -MF _muldi3.dep -DL_muldi3 -c ../.././libgcc/libgcc2.c -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from ../.././libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:87,
                 from ../.././libgcc/libgcc2.c:27:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/predefs.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:460: recipe for target '_muldi3.o' failed
make[3]: *** [_muldi3.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-20150611/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc'
Makefile:14787: recipe for target 'all-stage1-target-libgcc' failed
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-20150611'
Makefile:18655: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-20150611'
Makefile:884: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This article (https://superuser.com/questions/762274/error-compiling-gcc-on-raspberry-pi) doesn't fix my issue unfortunately.

Comment: No, you can't. C++11 Standard Library ABI is incompatible with C++03 ABI.

Comment: @SergeyA I was afraid you'd say that...